# Referring to Range address in a VBA entered formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Is it possible to enter a formula in VBA that refers to an address defined by a named range?

If my range is called "Table" I would reference a cell in the following way (with counters  "n_row" and "n_col")

`Range("Table")(n_row, n_col)`

How would I do this in a Cell formula?
The best I could come up with is this, which clearly didn't work.

`Range("Test").Formula = "=10 - Table(n_row, n_col)"`

Comment: The easiest way to learn new techniques in VBA is often to record a macro while performing the action programmatically, then to inspect the macro code. Try that here and see what it gives you, and come back with any questions that inspires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Index Formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/index-function-HP010069831.aspx)

```
Range("Test").Formula = "=10 -INDEX(Table," & n_row & "," & n_col & ")"
```

Comment: Not sure if the correct procedure is to edit your post or just to post a comment, but another suggestion is to use "OFFSET" instead of "INDEX" if  you're only using a single cell. Thanks though, your solution worked.

Comment: INDEX is preferred for a cell formula, since it isn't volatile.